# Using "href=tel:" in custom Azure B2C SSO HTML page

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to use a `<a href="tel://1300000">1300000</a>` link on any custom policies HTML page in Azure AD B2C SSO but `href="tel://1300000` is being stripped out and only `<a>1300000</a>` is visible in the page source thus negating the link.

I can understand why this is done when attempting to use the `<script>` tag as JavaScript is not permitted but I can't find any reference or logical reasoning as to why `tel:` or `tel://` are not permitted, I have also tried `callto:`, `auto-detected:`,`sms:` and `fax:` but these are also stripped.

If this is a limitation then some reasoning would be great, even better would be a possible workaround/solution.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This is no longer an issue due to MS allowing front end JS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples

The reasoning for this is due to the following code that is inserted into every custom HTML page in SSO;

[image]

As you can see only http,https,ftp and mailto are allowed.